# Display Photo Library Horizontally

Tags: iphone, photolibrary

Hey all,
I am developing a game in which I need to display all the view horizontally. Now the problem is when I open the photot library It gets diplayed in vertical view. So I want it also to be displayed horizontally.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImagePickerController` does not support the horizontal orientation. But you can build your own photo picker using the `AssetsLibrary.framework`. It's probably a lot of work but you are free to design it in any way you want.

Comment: Begemann. I have o idea how assetsLibrary.framework works. If possible can u pls pass on the link so that I can go through few examples..